# Using AVAudioplayer how to play audio in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, avaudioplayer

I am making Audioplayer using AVAudioplayerDelegate.The audio player functionality successfully Done.But i have small issues.I click the play button the audio lag is palpate at least 1 to 2 mins.this is my problem.Iam using audio urls.. The audio urls are there in local server.
This is my code

```
-(void)playOrPauseButtonPressed:(id)sender

{

[self.view addSubview:today_slokaText];

if(playing==NO)

{

[UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible=YES;


[playButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Pause.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

[self.view addSubview:today_slokaText];

 // Here Pause.png is a image showing Pause Buttomn

NSError *err=nil;

if (!audioPlayer)

{

[self loadSongAtIndex: selectedIndex];

playing=YES;

}

audioPlayer.numberOfLoops = 0;

[audioPlayer prepareToPlay];

[audioPlayer play];

audioPlayer.delegate=self;

if(!audioPlayer.playing)

{

[audioPlayer play];

activityIndicator = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleWhite];

[self.view addSubview:self.activityIndicator];

self.activityIndicator.center = CGPointMake(self.view.frame.size.width / 2, self.view.frame.size.height / 2);

[self.activityIndicator startAnimating];

[playButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Pause.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

[bg_Image addSubview:activityIndicator];

}

playing=YES;

}

else if (playing==YES)

{

[self.activityIndicator stopAnimating];

self.activityIndicator.alpha=0.0;

// [bg_Image addSubview:activityIndicator];

[playButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"play12.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

[self.view addSubview:today_slokaText];

[audioPlayer pause];

playing=NO;

timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0 target:self selector:@selector(updateViewForPlayerState) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];

[self.view addSubview:today_slokaText];

}

}

/******************************************

 load the song from service

 *******************************************/


- (void)loadSongAtIndex:(NSInteger) songIndex

{

audioSession=[AVAudioSession sharedInstance];

[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback error:nil];

[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setActive: YES error: nil];

[[UIApplication sharedApplication] beginReceivingRemoteControlEvents];

urlsArray=[[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"http://01_ARDHANAREESWARASTOTRAM.mp3",@"http://02_AshtaLakshmiStotram.mp3",@"http://03_AYIGIRINANDININANDITHAMEDINI.mp3",@"http://04_DurgaSahasranamamSthothram.mp3",@"http://05_GaneshaSahasranamaStotram.mp3",@"http://06_GaneshaStotram.mp3",@"http://07_HanumanChalisa.mp3",@"http://08_LakshmiAshtothram.mp3", nil];

dispatch_queue_t dispatchQueue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0);

dispatch_async(dispatchQueue, ^(void)

{

NSString *sourcePath = [urlsArray objectAtIndex:songIndex];

NSURL *audioURL=[NSURL URLWithString:sourcePath];

NSData *data=[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:audioURL];

audioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithData:data  error:NULL];

audioPlayer.numberOfLoops = 0;

[audioPlayer prepareToPlay];

[audioPlayer play];

audioPlayer.delegate=self;

if(!audioPlayer.playing)

{

[audioPlayer play];

}

if (self.audioPlayer)

{

[self updateViewForPlayerInfo];

[self updateViewForPlayerState];

[self.audioPlayer setDelegate:self];

}

});

}
```